# How to change the message "*!* whispers to you"?

Tags: minecraft-commands, minecraft-bedrock-edition

When I type `/msg @p xxxxx`, it always says `*!* whispers to you: xxxx`. How do I change this to a name, like `xxx: xxxxx`, instead?
I'm on the Windows 10 Edition for Xbox One.

Comment: Are you on a server or just playing with friends? And do you mind if other people to see the message, or just the intended recipient?

Comment: If you say something to yourself, of course the chat will state that you said it, because that's true. If you want full control of the entire text in chat, use `/tellraw`.

Comment: The only way I know of to do this is trough server plugins.

Comment: I should've been more specific, I put the commands in command blocks. I don't mind who sees it if it's too much of an issue, but would prefer the person who pressed the button (@p). I'm in a standard creative world.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I should've been more specific, I put the commands in command blocks. I don't mind who sees it if it's too much of an issue, but would prefer the person who pressed the button (@p). I'm in a standard creative world.

If the command is in a command block then you need to change the command block name (technically "Hover Note") to what you want it to be. Then when you run the command, it will read:

`[ChosenName] whispers to you: {Message}`

Additionally, if you only want the person who pressed the button to see it, use `@p` in the command. After this change, your command will look like this:

`/msg @p {Message}`

[image: Command block GUI]